# Circuit to identify phase difference between capacitor voltages of two different RLC circuits without loading it

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, phase-shift

I am looking for a circuit that can translate phase difference of two sinusoidal signals (operating at ~1MHz) to analog voltage swing of 0 - 5V.

The signal A & B comes from the capacitors of two different RLC circuits.The conditioning circuit should not load the circuit as it will change the RLC filter circuit operating point.

I could think about digitizing sine signal + EXOR + filtering but, the RLC capacitor that I am using is about 50pF and using MOSFET for digitizing didnt help as gate input capacitance did change the operating point of the previous stage.

Another option, I was thinking is using a voltage follower opamp + EXOR + filter and I am looking for opamps that can have inputs > 20V with supply voltage of 5V and operating at >1MHz. Any ideas?

Additionally, I came across CD4046B, but I believe that it also needs digitizing before it is fed into the signal & comparator Inputs.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

**EDIT1:**

Below is a rudimentary circuit (Please ignore part numbers). If the loading is limited to a few 10uAs, then I beleive the operating point would not shift that much.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a complete circuit with the RLC's

Comment: XOR gate is simple with buffered signals. then LPF gives DC.  But not bipolar in phase with voltage, so show impedance specs of all expected interface signals and purpose.  20~30V sounds like an IAPS

Comment: It's impossible to measure a circuit without loading it _somehow_; what amount of loading is tolerable?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: You WILL have some capacitance; with major effort you might achieve 1pF or 0.5pF, with major effort. How much will you spend on this?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75: The 20-30 V comes from the capacitor voltage swing and depends on the quality factor of the RLC filter.

Comment: @VoltageSpike: For 1 MHz operation, I have chosen, C = 50pF and L in test to be around 400 - 500 uH.

Comment: @Hearth: Well, I expect some 10uAs should be possible

Comment: @winny: Not a homework. Just an idea. Trying to put pieces together to get a working concept

Comment: @analogsystemsrf: Well, unless a single component does not cost more than 1-2$, it should be fine.

Comment: Tap the L at 10% to get 2V swing and 1% of the loading.

Comment: your concept needs refinement, what is it?  why re-invent wheel?

Comment: The 4046 will take fractional-volt analogue signals into the comparator.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75: I am unable to find direct solutions which can just give me phase difference of two signals.  I am definitely open for suggestions :)

Comment: @BrianDrummond: The LC circuit is out of my reach. The only output I get is the capacitor voltages

Comment: U cannot use hi Q LC due to induced phase errors with tolerances

Comment: Yes. I agree. I am also looking to the possibilities of reducing the Q so that the slope is not that steep to accommodate tolerances.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGTdts.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yes Indeed. Thanks :)